# How do I determine the users local system date format

Tags: vb.net, datetime, format

I'm trying to determine the system date format from vb.net which must match the format which would be shown from cmd prompt.

Example, if you type `date` in cmd prompt (you may need to run it as admin)
it will output the format required for the date change to take effect, similar to this:

`The current date is: Sun 05/28/2017
Enter the new date: (mm-dd-yy)`

My current date shown in my taskbar is also `05/28/2017`

From vb.net, I need to find out the requested format, which in this case was `mm-dd-yy`.

I have tried `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern()` which outputted `dd/MM/yyyy` which doesn't match the format.

Comment: I don't know this for sure but, given that the format requested for input doesn't match the output format, I'd say that that input format is constant and not culture dependent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working using this:

```
Private Function CheckDateFormat1()
    Dim Format As String = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortDatePattern

    If Format.Contains("MMM") Then
        Format = Format.Replace("MMM", "MM")
    ElseIf Format.Contains("MMMM") Then
        Format = Format.Replace("MMMM", "MM")
    End If

    If Format.Contains("dddd") Then
        Format = Format.Replace("dddd", "dd")
    End If

    Return Format
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Going by Window's official documentation on the "Date" command, it is just hard coded output and will accept any separator as long as they are "/", ".", or "-". See the Documentation here:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732776(v=ws.11).aspx

However, the `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern()` command should output the User's Current Local System Date format; that or the MSDN Documentation is wrong.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shortdatepattern(v=vs.110).aspx